# Can red5 server be used for live streaming of mpeg2 files to Flv players?

Tags: streaming, video, red5

(new to media streaming so please forgive my ignorance)

I need to provide live streaming to FLV players out of MPEG2 encoded video files. Clients must NOT be able to START/STOP/FF/RW the video, just connect to the stream and play what is currently on broadcast.

My question has two parts:

(a) is this possible at all (does the FLV format allow live streaming); and:

(b) can I use the **red5 server** for this? (Suggestions for other options are welcome.)

I tried reading the **red5** wiki but still I am not sure whether it can help.

Your help is highly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Both flv and mp4 (nitpicking aside) allow for live streaming.

Flash does not read mpeg2 as far as I know, you'll have to transcode it on the fly. Red5 can use ffmpeg for this, so it should work.
Other options touting this functionality are Flumotion and Wowza, both commercial software.